# bad substitution in Jenkins command when using an environment variables

Tags: bash, jenkins

From the Jenkins UI under `Build / Execute Shell / Command` I'm running:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
docker push 10.0.0.200:8080/myapp:${env.BUILD_NUMBER}
```

but I'm getting

> ${env.BUILD_NUMBER}: bad substitution

I tried to surround it with quotes but it didn't solve the issue

How to fix this command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by replacing `${env.BUILD_NUMBER}` with `${BUILD_NUMBER}`